Extraction of road data from a tiff file
I am brand new to QGIS and i have been assigned to take out the road network map from a given map (in tiff format).
The main aim is to extract the road network map only from the whole map.
I need suggestions to how to do so and other methods to extract would be highly appreciated.
I am running QGIS on linux system
I have converted the raster layer to the vector layer.
I need further guidance to how to achieve or progress towards the end result.

Welcome to SO. This site is for asking specific programming questions. Your question is broad and vague, and more a conceptual questions (what should I aim for) or a how-to-use QGIS software. A question like this would be more appropriate at https://gis.stackexchange.com/ but even for that site, the question may be too vague as  it is written now.
